# Magento Payment Module, no automatic invoicing

Tags: magento, payment

We are using a custom cash-on-pickup payment method. Problem however is that Magento by default seems to put the items as 'invoiced' eventhough the payment will only take place when they pick up the goods.

How do I tell magento NOT to make an invoice when the client is finalizing its order?

There seems to be no default function or anything as far as I have seen.

Does anyone know from the payment module to tell Magento NOT to do this?

As I seem to not be able to post an image, here the link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBTvU.gif

Comment: Can you change the default Order status for that payment method in the back end Admin section?

Comment: Yes I can, but the order status is not related to the invoicing. It invoices by default no matter what the stutus is. Already changed the default status to 'Pending'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a payment module configuration/coding thing. On this method, I think you can edit it to fit your needs, I can help you if you tell me the URL for the module on the Magento Connect website and your Magento version.

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks for your help but I solved the problem by just building a new payment module. That seemed simpler :).